# Image with hyperlink in jQuery datatables not showing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a `div` container in my aspx site which I fill behind with a `datatable`:

```
int[] Center = { 0, 5, 7 };

        string html = "<table id='Liste' class='display' cellspacing='0' style='width:100%'><thead>";
        //add header row
        html += "<tr>";

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Center.Contains(i)) html += "<th align='center'>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>";
            else html += "<th>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>";
        }

        html += "</tr></thead><tbody>";
        //add rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int y = 0; y <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; y++)
            {
                if (y == 8 || y == 9) { html += "<td align='center'>" + Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][y].ToString()).ToShortDateString() + "</td>"; }
                else
                {
                    if (y == 10)
                    {
                        html += "<td align='center'><a href='Details.aspx'><img scr='images/Calendar.png'></a></td>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Center.Contains(y)) html += "<td align='center'>" + dt.Rows[i][y].ToString() + "</td>";
                        else html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][y].ToString() + "</td>";
                    }
                }
            }
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        //footer
        html += "</tbody><tfoot><tr>";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) html += @"<th>" + dc.ColumnName + "</th>";
        html += "</tr></tfoot></table>";

        html += @"<script>

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                      $('#Liste').DataTable({

                                fixedHeader: {
                                                header: true,
                                                footer: true
                                            },

                                paging: false,

                                columnDefs: [{ type: 'de_date', targets: 8}, 
                                            { type: 'de_date', targets: 9}
                                             ]
                      });
                    });
                   </script>";

        DIV_Table.InnerHtml = html;
```

In Cell 10 should the image be shown with the hyperlink:

```
if (y == 10)
{
html += "<td align='center'><a href='Details.aspx'><img scr='images/Calendar.png'></a></td>";
}
```

The image is not shown n the table. If I mark the table the image "container" is shown with the right size and the hyperlink is working by clicking on the "container". If I click on the properties of the "container" its all shown "not available" expect the size (which is right).

[image]

I tried to render the Column 10 but this is not working:

```
{ targets: 10,
  render: function(data){
   return '<img src='images/Calendar.png'>'}
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because of the typo in your `img` tag?

```
...><img scr='images/Calendar.png'></...
```

which should of course read 'src' as it does in your last code snippet. But won't that last bit of code have a problem because of the quotes in the `return` string?

Answer (score 1):

You have put scr instead of src in the attribute of your tag img